# Check all CheckBoxes on Button Click,ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change all checkboxes to the `checked`,But problem is I don't know how to get all of them.
Any suggestions?
Here is what I'm trying to do

```
 checkAllCheckBox = () => {
    let {todos} = this.state
    let newArray = [...todos]
    if (newArray.length === 0) {
        alert('HOW CAN CHECK NOTHING YOU STUPED')
    } else {
        newArray.forEach(item => {
            item.checked = true;
        })
    }
   this.setState({todos: newArray})
   console.log('----todos',todos)


 }




render() {


    const {itemsPerPage, currentPage, todos} = this.state;

    console.log('--------todos', todos);

    const end = currentPage * itemsPerPage
    const start = end - itemsPerPage
    const currentItems = todos.slice(start, end);
    return <div className={"App"}>
        <div className="App-header">
            <h2>Welcome to To-Do List App</h2>
        </div>
        <input ref={this.inpRef} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} name={''} type='text'/>
        <button onClick={() => this.addItem()} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Add</button>
        <button  onClick={() => this.checkAllCheckBox()}
          className={'btn btn-primary'}>Check All</button>
        <ul>
            {
                currentItems.map(todoItem => {
                    return <ListItem
                        key={todoItem._id}
                        todoItem={todoItem}
                        deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
                        editItem={this.editItem}
                        submitEdit={this.submitEdit}
                        deleteData = {this.deleteData}
                    />
                })
            }
            <div>
                {this.renderPagination()}
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
};
```

}

export default App;

Code for    `<ListItem>`

```
    import React, {Component, createRef} from "react";


class itemList extends Component {
    state = {
        isEditMode: false
    }
    inputRef = createRef();
    btnRef = createRef();

    render() {
        const {isEditMode} = this.state;
        const {todoItem, submitEdit, deleteItem} = this.props;

        return <li>
            {
                isEditMode ? (
                    <div>
                        <input
                            ref={this.inputRef}
                            defaultValue={todoItem.inputValue} type={'text'}
                        />
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                submitEdit(todoItem._id, this.inputRef.current.value);
                                this.setState({isEditMode: !isEditMode});
                            }}
                            className={'btn btn-primary'}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                this.setState({isEditMode: !isEditMode})
                            }}
                            className={'btn btn-primary'}
                        >Cancel
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <input ref={this.btnRef} type={'checkbox'}/>
                        <label>
                            {todoItem.todo}
                        </label>
                        <button onClick={() => {
                            deleteItem(todoItem._id)
                        } } className={'btn btn-primary'}>Delete
                        </button>
                        <button onClick={() => this.setState({isEditMode: !isEditMode})} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Edit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </li>

    }

}


export default itemList;
```

Comment: I assume ListItem is your checkbox, could you post the code, please?

Comment: Sure,I updated the post

Comment: you need to add the checked prop to the input like this `<input ref={this.btnRef} type={'checkbox'} checked={todoItem.checked}/>`

Comment: just change this line `<input ref={this.btnRef} type={'checkbox'}/>` for this `<input ref={this.btnRef} type={'checkbox'} checked={todoItem.checked}/>` in your ListItem component and it should work

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, let me know if it works

Comment: Yep,It worked perfectly